# Change flash message on devise password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am changing my password and the flash message is showing "You are already signed in." and I want to show "You password is changed successfully.

I have searched what to do and one recommendation was to use i8n but I am looking for an alternate solution

My edit.html.erb is given as:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, id:'edit-pwd-profile' }) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :current_password %>
            <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" , class: "form-control"%>
        </div>

        <div class="actions form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Update", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I expect "Your password is changed successfully"
Actual output is "You are already signed in."

Comment: Are you sure you want your app to show a broken English message "You password is changed successfully["]?

Comment: Copy this file [en.yml](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml) into your `config/locales` and rename it to `devise.en.yml` after that change this key `passwords: -> updated` in your `devise.en.yml`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `config/devise.en.yml`

update flash messages by taking reference from `/home/<username>/.rvm/gems/<ruby-version>/gems/devise-<version-installed>/config/locales/en.yml`

If you do not want to show flash message / remove it, just provide key with blank value.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain or provide a link for reference?

Comment: We can override devise flash messages, but structure must be followed, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20782770/10522579

Comment: I do not know which `devise` and `ruby` version you are using. Your devise.en.yml structure depends on which devise version you are using.